# Encrypt InMemoryUploadfile and save the encrypted file on disk

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I searched for different solution for encryption for user uploaded file. All of the tutorials or solution which i found where about opening an existing file on the disk encrypting it and and saving it to the disk. I am trying to encrypt the user uploaded file with out saving the original file and directly saving the encrypted file.
Right now 
user upload > save to disk > open the file > encrypt it >save the encrypted file > delete the original file i am doing this now.

```
def upload_file:
for file_name, each_file in request.FILES.items():
incoming_file = each_file
save_path = "abc/%s/%s" % (request.user, user_id)
abs_filename = os.path.join(settings.PATH, save_path)
normalize_path = os.path.normpath(abs_filename)
if not os.path.exists(abs_filename):
os.makedirs(abs_filename)
path = normalize_path
if os.path.exists(os.path.normpath(abs_filename)):
path = normalize_path
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=path)  # (location='/media/')
doc_data = incoming_file.read()
filename = incoming_file.name
size_a = incoming_file.size
content_type = incoming_file.content_type
filename = fs.save(incoming_file.name.replace(" ","_"), incoming_file)
Document(document_type=content_type,file_name=filename,document_path="media/abc/" + filename,file_size=size_a,contract_id=data,user_id=user_id,original_path=path).save()
return
```

Comment: User uploads via HTML FORM ? You could use python io.BytesIO ? Not sure what is your goal, but you could consider writing the files to a encrypted partition.

Comment: yes data is been sent with html form and  file_data = request.FILES and if i do file_data.file i am getting io.BytesIO object

Comment: writing on an encrypted partition is good suggestion i never thought of that. Thanks @Roger

Comment: Just found that we already have an encrypted partition.

Comment: alright, cool 

Comment: We want to file level encryption too so I don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is? You get your data (as base64 ?) you can encrypt that, *then* store on disk ? Maybe you can post the code?

Comment: Right now i just have very simple structure.
1. I get my data in request.FILES-->
2. Loop around request.FILES and get each_file-->
3. get the inmemoryuploadedfile in a variable-->
4. Using FileSystemStorage(location=normalize_path) i save the file with name in the directory

Comment: you should post the code. https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/ here you can use BytesIO so there is no need to write the file intermediate to disk and then encrypt it. However, I'm not sure what Django does when the data comes in (might write it somewhere on disk as-well).

Comment: @Roger posted my sample code which i use to save files on disk. for pyAesCrypt is in python 3 not useful for me.

Comment: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic